# Unity Raycast2D ScreenPointToRay gives an ERROR

Tags: unity-game-engine, error-handling, raycasting, ray

I want to create a simple Ray2D with my mouse Position:

```
//Create a ray
Ray2D ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;
```

It gives me an error: Ray can't be converted into Ray2D
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you think you need a `Ray2D`? You are using a `RaycastHit` .. I don't know any case where a `RaycastHit` is returned by something using a `Ray2D` ... Could you post more code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using "ScreenPointToRay" which returns a "Ray" not a "Ray2D".

Try this:

```java
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
```